# Azure Artifacts fails to provide package

Tags: .net-core, azure-artifacts

We use our own Azure Artifacts instance to provide a private Nuget feed. It has a default setup, with the @Local view as the default view.

After updating a project on one of the developer machines from dotnet core 3.x to 5.0 all went fine on the dev machine. But then other developers started getting problems with restoring packages.

These developers tried `dotnet nuget locals all -c` then `dotnet clean && dotnet restore` after making sure they have the correct SDK installed (5.0). But the Azure Artifacts server cannot provide the correct package version, specifically;

`error NU1102: Unable to find package Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref with version (= 5.0.0)`

I am aware that this package is an "internal package" in dotnet, and I have confirmed that it is not explicitly defined as a dependency in the projects that reports errors. It is some sort of implicit dependency.

I am also aware of that Microsoft says that one must add packages to a private feed that one wants the consumers of the feed to have available.

1. How can I possibly add such an "internal package" to the Nuget feed, when it is not meant to be consumed explicitly?
2. Why cannot Microsoft query a upstream package source when the requested package is not found in the private feed? (the 5.0.0 package version actually exists on nuget!)
3. How come that I do not have to download such a package myself when running `dotnet restore`, but my peers have to? (and fails at it, even though their dev environment is similar to mine)

Comment: Please check if you [configured upstream sources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/how-to/set-up-upstream-sources?view=azure-devops) in your feed.

Comment: @WalterQian-MSFT The upstream sources are configured; it is pointing at the public nuget feed. The users are all "contributors".

Comment: [This package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref/) seems not used by any NuGet packages. How does your project reference this package?